# SharePoint 2010-"Cannot connect to the configuration database"

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I have TFS 2012 which integrated with SharePoint service, recently I duplicated the same machine for testing, and modified some parameters on the testing machine to avoid conflict due to they are in the same networking. They works well.

Today the production server's SharePoint site prompt "`Cannot connect to the configuration database`", but team foundation service works well, I doubt that something in the testing server cause this, and I shutdown testing server, the issue still exists.

Before I have experience for this issue, most of them are related with SQL server instance configuration like this "https://mikessharepoint.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/cannot-connect-to-the-configuration-database-error-of-central-administration/" or some authentications issue in the IIS application pool.

and here is the error event from event viewer:
"

```
Unknown SQL Exception 53 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

"

I doubt that something (probably SQL server instance name) on production server change to testing servers by some action, but I don't know where and how.

And I doubt that the new server cause the error, the reason is I find something incorrect in wss_config database of production server, the "ServerName" filed in table TimerJobHistory, some value are new server, some value are old server. But even I update all the value to old server and restarted the production server, it does not work.

I check all things I can googled, but nothing works, is there anybody could provide any help on this, appreciate for any kindly help.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer your question: I'd recommend updating to a recent version of TFS. Sharepoint integration has been essentially useless for years, and as of TFS 2018 is completely removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is not easy to update in production environment. It will be a project for us.

Comment: @Mac Lee Just try to disable TCP/IP chimney on all servers in the farm. Check this similar issue : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb5f4b8b-79b5-4644-90f9-9adde3c43242/sharepoint-database-connectivity-errors?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: Also check if the SQL instance for Team foundation server is on a custom port which is different with the Analysis services port. Refer to this article for details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2014/05/28/error-on-sharepoint-portal-if-tfs-is-configured-on-a-custom-port-for-sql-server/  More information to troubleshoot the issue you can refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci/32458013#32458013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the root reason, there is a table named "Objects" in the "Wss_config" DB, I find the new testing server name in "Name" filed, so I update the value to old server name-->Restarted IIS and SharePoint service (not sure if required)-->Bingo!
But I still don't know why the new server cause this error, so I have not power on the new server for now. Will update if any new detection.

Thanks all for your kindly help.